# How to make element hidden by "***" accessible?

Tags: html, angular, accessibility

I have a small functionality that hides connection string by displaying ***.
[image]

Currently my code looks like this

```html
<div class="label-wrapper">
    <label class="label">{{label}}</label>

    <button class="value-hide-button"
            (click)="toggleValueHide()"
            *ngIf="_secret"
    >
        <qst-icon class="secret-icon"
                  name="rf-eye"
                  aria-label="Show Secret"
                  title="Show Secret"
                  *ngIf="valueHidden"
        ></qst-icon>

        <qst-icon class="secret-icon"
                  name="rf-eye-closed"
                  aria-label="Hide Secret"
                  title="Hide Secret"
                  *ngIf="!valueHidden"
        ></qst-icon>
    </button>

</div>
<div class="value"
     [ngSwitch]="valueHidden"
>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="true">**********</ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="false">{{value}}</ng-container>

</div>
```

How do I indicate that a value is hidden using ***?

Comment: Have you read the code? It already has conditional rendering. I am looking for a11y attribute that would indicate to a screen reader that the value is visible but obfuscated.

Comment: Probably would be better to use a password input for the masked state - that will communicate all the right things to AT and will not announce keystrokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `<span>` that is visually hidden but there for screen readers which will provide them more information. 
So you could do
`<label class="label">{{label}} <span class="visuallyhidden">The password is hidden for security reasons</span></label>`
And use a `type="password"` for any input fields